# Completely antisymmetric unit tensor of fourth rank in different 4D coordinate systems

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, inertial-frames, invariants

I am reading Landau's Classical Theory of Fields. On page 18, it is said that the completely antisymmetric unit tensor of fourth rank $\varepsilon^{iklm}$ is defined as the same in all coordinate systems. I have no idea if this is true. If so, how can this be shown by a math derivation?

Comment: I haven't read Landau's field theory book, so I don't know the context, but didn't you say it was a definition? It is a bit weird to ask for a proof of a definition, so I can't really tell what this question is asking

Comment: @Nickolas Alves: Don't you have to show that such a tensor is possible? ie existence. I can define a crimson unicorn but it doesn't mean one exists ...

Comment: @Nickolas Alves: In the book, that tensor is defined in a certain frame and the authors' meaning is that we therefore can deduce that the tensor has the same form in all frames.

Comment: @rioiong To be clear, you mean all *inertial* frames? (related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Tensor_density)

Comment: @Nickolas Alves: In the book, the original line is "in all coordinate systems".

Comment: beware of distinction between tensor and tensor density here; Landau might not be making this distinction clear in his choice of words (but the maths will be correct)